# Компания оказалась наедине с кем-либо, - можно?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Наша **компания осталась наедине с женщиной** средних лет, которая ещё
>   несколько минут назад взялась из ниоткуда и каким-то чудом, и в
>   мгновение ока, обнесла всех нас стопочками, точнее узкими крохотными,
>   вытянутыми, стеклянными кувшинчиками – они называются чоканчичи.

Интересуют также запятые: *и в мгновение ока; точнее узкими крохотными, вытянутыми, стеклянными*, - как бы это в порядок привести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что компания в силу своей множественности не может оказаться наедине (= один на один) с кем-либо персонально. Здесь по контексту может подойти такое:

> Наша компания оказалась *на попечении* (*была оставлена на попечение*,
>   *была предоставлена заботам* и т. п.) женщины... и каким-то чудом в
>   мгновение ока обнесла всех нас стопочками, точнее, узкими, крохотными,
>   вытянутыми стеклянными кувшинчиками.

Мне показалось лишним второе "и", запятые при однородных перечисляемых эпитетах и при "мгновении ока", в котором заключалось "чудо"; добавил запятую после вводного "точнее".

Answer (score 1):

*Наедине* - один на один с кем-нибудь, вдвоём без свидетелей; с глазу на глаз.

То есть "*компания осталась наедине*" - это не совсем корректно.

Первое "*и*" соединяет однородные сказуемые "*взялась*" и "*обнесла*".

Второе "*и*" соединяет однородные элементы "*каким-то чудом*" и "*в мгновение ока*", которые не являются сказуемыми. Запятая между ними не должна стоять. Но лучше эту "*и*" вообще не использовать, она не звучит.

"*В мгновение ока*" уточнением не является - запятая после этой фразы не нужна.

*Узкими, крохотными, вытянутыми* - однородные определения, между которыми нужны запятые.

*Стеклянными* - неоднородно по отношению к трём предыдущим, это описание материала, а не характеристика. Перед данным словом запятую лучше не ставить.

Результат:

> Наша компания осталась с женщиной средних лет, которая ещё несколько минут назад взялась из ниоткуда и каким-то чудом (и) в мгновение ока обнесла всех нас стопочками, точнее узкими, крохотными, вытянутыми стеклянными кувшинчиками – они называются чоканчичи.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *В нашей компании  оказалась только (осталась только) только женщина средних лет, которая ещё несколько минут назад взялась из ниоткуда и каким-то чудом,  **в мгновение ока**, обнесла всех нас стопочками, точнее **узкими, крохотными, вытянутыми стеклянными кувшинчиками** – они называются чоканчичи.*

Обособлен уточняющий оборот ***в мгновение ока*** (чудом, в мгновение ока).

Однородными являются только определения, отнесенные к форме и размеру (об этом уже сказано).

(2) *Наша компания осталась с женщиной средних лет....*

Можно просто опустить слово ***наедине.***